# How to remove broken freeze plug adapter in a spa pump

Tags: plumbing, repair, hot-tub

[image]

This is the wet end of the Emerson pump in my Jacuzzi spa.  Pictured above is a broken freeze plug adapter.  The freeze plug adapter threads into the pump (lower center of pic).  It broke with part of the threaded end still in the pump.  What is the best way to remove the part that remains in the pump?  None of these parts are metal.

Answer (score 1):

Drill a hole in it, then use a standard screw extractor. But a new plug and re-install. FYI, its not a freeze plug. It is used to let trapped air out of the pump before priming on initial fill/refill and startup.

Comment: Thanks.  (1) It's actually called a "freeze plug adapter." (https://www.spadepot.com/Pump-Freeze-Drain-Plug-Barb-Adapter-P2881) (2) there is nothing to drill because it is the hollow, male part that is threaded into the pump. (3) I've been able to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, Isaw the freeze plug in the upper portion of the pic and assumed it was still hooked up, and therefore assumed that you were looking to remove the pump drain cock. Ishould have looked closer at the picture! Sorry. Anyway since you have it out, another tool is a PVC pipe extractor. If you can find one small enough.

Answer (score 0):

There's a tool for just this sort of thing: a sprinkler riser extractor. The pointed tip is pressed into the broken-off threaded part and turned counter-clockwise. The splines on the tool dig into the walls of the plastic part and cause it to rotate. Thanks goes to Lowe's and to Orbit for the photo.

[image: sprinkler riser extractor tool]